# Formatting PHP for when it posts and emails

Tags: php, email, post

I have a block of code that takes a form, posts it to the same page with a thank you message and then proceeds to email it to my account.

As of right now, it displays like this in the email end:

```
hello world., Name: Hello World, , Email: HelloWorld@fake.com
```

Which means it goes message, name, then email.

How can I make it so it displays similar to something like this in the email..

```
Name: Hello World
Email: HelloWorld@fake.com

Message: hello world...
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
    //if "email" is filled out, send email
       {
            //send email
            $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
            $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
            $subject = $_REQUEST["My Portfolio Website"] ;
            $message = $_REQUEST['message'].", Name: ".$name.", Email: ".$email;
            mail("MyEmail@gmail.com", $subject, $message, "From:" . $email);
            echo "<h1>Thank you for contacting me. I will get back to you ASAP!</h1>";
        }else{
        //if "email" is not filled out, display the form
            echo "<form method='post' action='index.php'>

                <input type='text' input name='name' id='name' class='contacttext' placeholder='Your Name' required>
                <input type='text' input name='email' id='email' class='contacttext' placeholder='Your Email Address' required>
                <textarea name='message' id='message' class='contacttext' placeholder='Your Message' cols='55' rows='5' required></textarea>

                <input type='submit' id='submit' class='submitcontacttext' value='Send'>
                </form>";
        }
?>
```

Also, currently the subject is not setting itself, what would be the cause of this?

Comment: html inputs with spaces are converted to underscores `_` in php, so you need `$_REQUEST["My_Portfolio_Website"]`. To format, use linebreaks `\n`/`\r\n`

Comment: have you tried anything? doesn't look like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
// I don't see 'My Portfolio Website' this being passed into your form
// did you mean to do? $subject = 'My Portfolio Website';
$subject = $_REQUEST["My Portfolio Website"];
// add \n to add line breaks.
// $message = $_REQUEST['message'] . "\nName: " . $name . "\nEmail: ".$email;

/**
 * this will make it easier to re-order the elements or add new ones.
 */
$message = implode("\n", [
    'Name: ' . $name,
    'Email: ' . $email,
    'Message ' . $_REQUEST['message'],
]);
```

Comment: Would I just add `"\nMessage: " .$message` at the end of this to get it to format so it sends name/email, then messages, like in my example? As of right now, calling the `$message = $_REQUEST['message']` is making it so the message is the first thing displayed in the email.

Comment: yes you can do that.

Comment: Will that duplicate the message function?
`$message = $_REQUEST['message'] . "\nName: " . $name . "\nEmail: ".$email;  "\n \nMessage: ".$message;`

Comment: I added a new example which will make it easier to work with.